# Debian Heartbeat IP Configuration

Tags: debian, failover, heartbeat

I need to setup a heartbeat with pacemaker based on debian OS where the active server virtual IP is 192.168.1.10 and the passive server virtual IP is 192.168.1.11. Both of the server is connected to a cisco ethernet switch. My question is, do setup the heartbeat for the 2 servers, do i need 2 more separate virtual IP for heartbeat or can I use 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11 for the heartbeat configuration to listen for the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dedicated NIC for heartbeat and maybe (depends on your needs) sync the data using DRBD. A good start point is in [Debian Clusters From Scratch](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian-HA/ClustersFromScratch).
Please, read the [Debian-HA FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian-HA/FAQ) too. 
And for a DRBD howto, read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DrBd).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. If the setup were to be done using a dedicated NIC which connect to a separate network, I know that it could be a problem if a fault happened on the main network (ex: server 1 to switch connection broken). In this case, the heartbeat will not switch over to server 2 as the heartbeat is still alive. I did some googling, which I know this can be resolve using pacemaker pingd. My question would be, will it be an issue if i were to stick with 1 NIC instead of having a dedicated NIC, such as package lost on a 1Gbps network?

Comment: IMHO, could generate a performance issue. If some user flood the chanel, the slave could stop seeing the master and create a split-brain situation.